Can't create a Report Server Project in VS 2022
This is likely something that has an obvious solution, but I cannot find it for the life of me. I cannot create a Report Server Project in Visual Studio 2022.
VS2022 was just updated to v17.11.4. I made certain that the SQL Server Data Tools were included. After the update, I installed the Microsoft Reporting Services Extension. After restarting VS, I still cannot create a Report Server Project. Any suggestions are appreciated. (I'm new here so I can't post the screenshots).

can you confirm that the extension has been successfully applied by going into Extension - >Manage Extension  -> Installed and see if you can locate Microsoft Reporting Services Project

I do have it installed. I checked that a few times to be certain. Everything appears to be in place according to the instructions I've found.
